# Is there a way to get good `#inspect` output for Java objects in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Say we have a fairly straightforward Java bean:

```
public class Test {
    private String thing;

    public void setThing(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    public String getThing() {
        return thing;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{thing=" + thing + "}>";
    }
}
```

And then we use this bean from Ruby:

```
java_import 'Test'

t = Test.new
t.thing = 'blah'
p t
```

The output is:

```
#<Java::Default::Test:0x5fdba6f9>
```

But I think what I'd prefer is something like

```
#<Test{thing=blah}>
```

Or possibly even just

```
Test{thing=blah}
```

I know that I could add a method called `inspect()` to all my Java classes, but it seems like every single implementation is just going to call `toString()` anyway, because the intent of `toString()` in Java is usually the same as the intent of `#inspect` in Ruby anyway (i.e., a string only intended to be seen by developers).

So what I'm wondering is, is there a straightforward way to tell JRuby to use `toString()` when `#inspect` is called on any Java object?

Comment: for the record, this isn't ideal in JRuby itself - it might eventually include a solution since most tools such as rspec use inspect ... https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/5182

Comment: @kares rspec is one of our use cases, yeah. Sometimes you get expectation failures where the "actual" is a hash you can't read to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in any other ruby implementation we would just monkey patch the `Object#inspect` method, but that is not possible for Java classes because their implementation is native. But you could do something like this to make your life easier:

```
module JavaInspect
  alias_method :inspect_without_to_string, :inspect
  def inspect_with_string
    self.respond_to?(:toString) ? self.toString : self.inspect_without_to_string
  end
  alias_method :inspect, :inspect_with_string
end

java_import 'Test'
Test.include(JavaInspect)
t = Test.new
t.inspect => "Test{thing=null}>"
t.inspect_without_to_string => "#<Java::Default::Test:0x4efac082>"
```

The you just have to include your module into the classes you want. If you are really into it you can even create a wrapper around `java_import`.

Please, note that I don't recommend monkey patching `Object`, or creating any wrappers like this for production code, however in development this can be really useful, and in some cases after careful consideration it might even be used in production.

Comment: It’s 2018, consider using `Module#prepend` and call `super` instead of Rails-like hacks with aliases and `include`.

Comment: Yes, it will achieve the same effect, however in that case your prepended module will have to define two methods (or still use an alias) if you want to preserve access to the unmodified original method, which is a good practice. Honestly, is there any other issue with using include and aliases for this case? aside from being too much rails-like?, as I understand if the inspect method were defined on the actual java class and I wanted to surround it with behavior then I'll have to use prepend, however this doesn't seem to be the case in question.

Comment: Aaaaactually, Java classes can be monkey-patched too, I'm just not sure I like monkey-patching in general. Maybe here it's an acceptable evil though.